# file_put_contents uploads 6KB zip which is damaged

Tags: php

I am receiving zip url with Ajax to my php script. If I directly put that url into browser tab then it downloads file successfully but If I use this into my php script then file_put_contents generates 6KB file but the actual file size is 48KB. 
Also when I try to extract, it shows error that file is damaged.

Here is my php code:

```
$url = "http://localhost/web/?_task=mail&_action=get&_mbox=INBOX&_uid=4&_token=LimZJJeCew7mbTJm2qEN29Vpd3YT2m7t&_part=1&_download=1";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$name = 'mark.zip';
file_put_contents($name, $content);
```

Comment: Are you sure the source file is correct? Try md5 on the content and compare to the content you know that is correct.

Comment: open the zip in a text editor and check its not a textual server error page.

Comment: Must be the server is expecting proper headers, cookies, user-agent, which you have in a browser and 6KB is a length of the error page that file is not found or access denied. Try to open that file in an editor / through `cat`.

Comment: or just `echo $content;` to see what is downloaded

Comment: opened file in editor and found out it's html code.

Comment: why I am getting html code instead of zip ? when I open this url in browser it successfully downloads ? is it expecting proper headers, cookies as @Axalix mentioned ?

Comment: You are trying to get access to your inbox, which is usually enabled only to logged in users, what means the browser has cookies that were obtained after login and which you don't pass with `file_get_contents`

Comment: @Axalix I am passing `_token=LimZJJeCew7mbTJm2qEN29Vpd3YT2m7t`